# Select images from subnodes in umbraco

Tags: image, xslt, umbraco

I have subnodes that contain an image. How do I select these and display them ? I only seem to be able to select and display the ID. The code I've used:

```
<xsl:value-of select="image"/>
```

How do I get this to display the actual image ? I'm using Umbraco 4.7. I'm sure this is simple, I just dont seem to be able to figure it out.

I have also tried this code below but it doesn't seem to look at the correct node. I think it is looking at the parent and not the child, but I'm not sure how to change this:

```
<xsl:variable name="media" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($currentPage/image, 0)" />

<xsl:if test="$media">
        <img src="{$media/umbracoFile}" alt="{$media/altText}" />
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731760/umbraco-xslt-issue ?

Comment: its a almost the same however this is a better description of what im trying to do as the other one seems to be a bit confusing on reflection

Comment: @macroj - In that case it's better to edit the original question than to ask it again.

Comment: please give your content structure

Answer (score 0):

> I have subnodes that contain an image. How do I select these and
>   display them ? I only seem to be able to select and display the ID.
>   The code I've used:
>
> ```
> <xsl:value-of select="image"/>
> ```

Because you have forgotten to post the XML document (Learn to do this !!!) this question is impossible to answer with certainty.

My guess is that you may be more successful if you use `<xsl:copy-of>` instead of `<xsl:value-of>`

The former copies the whole node (or nodeset) specified in the `select` attribute, while the latter only copies the string-value of the node (nodeset).

**Learn what is the difference between string value of a node-set and a copy of the nodes  of a nodeset**.

Answer (score 0):

Use `node()` to get the children:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/node()/image">
    <xsl:variable name="media" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(., 0)" />
    <xsl:if test="$media">
        <img src="{$media/umbracoFile}" alt="{$media/altText}" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this.

```
                <xsl:variable name="imageId" select="./image" />
                <xsl:if test="normalize-space($imageId)">
                    <xsl:variable name="image" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($imageId, false())" />

                    <img src="{$image/umbracoFile}" rel="prettyPhoto" />
                </xsl:if>
            </a> 
          </xsl:if>
```